# Printing out the value from a matrix

Tags: python, regex, linux, bash

I have a task which consumes arbit CPU and memory over time. It gives me an output executing the following linux command:

`mpstat -u 1 -P ALL`

The output looks like:

```
02:22:14 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
02:22:15 PM  all    4.51    0.00    0.11    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.37
02:22:15 PM    0    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.00
02:22:15 PM    1   **78.22**    0.00    0.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   20.79

02:22:15 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
02:22:15 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
02:22:15 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
02:22:15 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM    8    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM    9    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   11    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   13    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   14    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   15    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
02:22:15 PM   16    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   17    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   18    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   19    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
02:22:15 PM   20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   21    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   22    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
02:22:15 PM   23    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I want to grab the value located in 4th column and 3rd row a[3][4] i.e 78.22 every 20 seconds in bash/python/perl.
So the script I want, will execute the mpstat command and print out the value in the specified column and based on the values it creates a graph. I was thinking of appending the required value in a .dat file and run a gnuplot or and app which creates the graph.

Any suggestion on how to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the 3rd row and 4th cell using `awk`. The following code grabs this cell from `mpstat`'s output and appends it along with the current UNIX timestamp to a statistics file.

```
mpstat -u 1 -P ALL | awk 'NR==4 {print systime(), $4}' >> stats.txt
```

To run this command every 20 seconds:

```
watch -n 20 "mpstat -u 1 -P ALL | awk 'NR==4 {print systime(), \$4}' >> stats.txt"
```

Then plot with `gnuplot`:

```
cat stats.txt | gnuplot -p -e 'set datafile separator " "; plot "-" using 1:2 with lines'
```

Comment: On doing this:mpstat -u 1 -P ALL | awk 'NR==4 {print systime(), $4}' >> stats.txt, stats.txt ends out to be an empty file.

Comment: Also what I see is that it doesn't print out the values in continuity rather prints it once and stops. My objective is to continually keep a tab on CPU usage till the process runs hence this won't suffice but some improvements to it will be awesome.

Comment: You can repeat the command with a `while` loop or (my favorite) `watch`. Updated the original answer.

Comment: Are you still seeing an empty file? (I'm not sure after your second comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#!/bin/bash
function _mpstat() {
    while :; do
        arr=( $(mpstat -P 1 | tail -n 1) )
        echo "${arr[3]}"
        sleep 20
    done >> file.txt
}
_mpstat &
echo "_mpstat PID: $!"
```

**Explanation**

- `while :; do` Infinite loop
- `$(mpstat -P 1 | tail -n 1)` Mpstat only cpu 1 `-P 1`and tail `-n 1` the last line, return value `$()`
- `arr=( ... )` Commands return value to array
- `echo "${arr[3]}"` echo array index 3
- `sleep 20` Sleep for 20 seconds
- `>> file.txt` Send stdout to file within while loop block.
- `_mpstat &` Send the function to a background process `&`
- `echo "_mpstat PID: $!` Returns PID of function

You can grep the PID to display its parent and kill both when needed.